# I am working on a assignment where I have to create read-only sqlite database where user is NOT prompted to enter data

Tags: database, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I am Getting this error

```
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting sno=S01 city=London sname=Smith
                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: s.sno (code 1555)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:783)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1548)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1417)
                      at com.rough.problem.problem9.DatabaseHelper.insertdata(DatabaseHelper.java:112)
                      at com.rough.problem.problem9.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:84)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

And here is my code

```
package com.rough.problem.problem9;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;



import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import static android.provider.Contacts.SettingsColumns.KEY;
import static java.text.Collator.PRIMARY;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SPdb1.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "s";
    private static final String COL_1 = "sno";
    private static final String COL_2 = "sname";
    private static final String COL_3 = "city";

    /*public static final String TABLENAME = "p";
    public static final String COL1 = "pno";
    public static final String COL2 = "pname";
    public static final String COL3 = "cost";
    public static final String COL4 = "city";

    public static final String TABLENAMES = "sp";
    public static final String COLS1 = "sno";
    public static final String COLS2 = "pno";
    public static final String COLS3 = "qty";
*/


    private static final String[] COLUMNS = {COL_1, COL_2, COL_3};
   /* private static final String[] COLUMN = {COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4};
    private static final String[] COLUMNSS = {COLS1,COL2,COLS3};
*/
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "Create Table IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                COL_1 + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY COLLATE NOCASE," + //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED SPACE
                COL_2 + " TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE," + //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED SPACE
                COL_3 + " TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE" + //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED SPACE
                ");";
        db.execSQL(query);

       /* String querys = "Create Table IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLENAME + "(" +
                COL1 + " TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE," + //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED SPACE
                COL2 + " TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE," + //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED SPACE
                COL3 + " REAL NOT NULL," + //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED SPACE
                COL4 + " TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE" + //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED SPACE

                ");";
        db.execSQL(querys);

        String queryss = "Create Table IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLENAMES + "(" +
                COLS1 + " TEXT NOT NULL REFERENCES s(sno) COLLATE NOCASE," + //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED SPACE
                COLS2 + " TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE," + //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED SPACE
                COLS3 + " INTEGER NOT NULL" + //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED SPACE

                ");";
        db.execSQL(queryss); */
    }


    /*public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "Create Table IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                COL_1 + "TEXT PRIMARY KEY COLLATE NOCASE," +
                COL_2 + "TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE," +
                COL_3 + "TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE" +
                ");";
        db.execSQL(query);


    }*/

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // you can implement here migration process
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
      //  db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLENAME);
     //   db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLENAMES);

        onCreate(db);
    }





    public void insertdata (tableS tables){
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put(COL_1, tables.getSno());
            values.put(COL_2, tables.getSname());
            values.put(COL_3,tables.getCity());

            // insert
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            db.close();
        }

   /* public void insertdatap ( tableP tablep){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values1 = new ContentValues();

        values1.put(COL1, tablep.getPno());
        values1.put(COL2, tablep.getPname());
        values1.put(COL3, tablep.getCost());
        values1.put(COL4, tablep.getCity());

        // insert

        db.insert(TABLENAME,null,values1);
        db.close();
    }

    public void insertdatasp ( tableSP tablesp){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values2 = new ContentValues();

        values2.put(COLS1,tablesp.getSno());
        values2.put(COLS2,tablesp.getPno());
        values2.put(COLS3,tablesp.getQty());

        // insert
        db.insert(TABLENAMES,null,values2);
        db.close();
    } */


}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.rough.problem.problem9;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText Select;
    DatabaseHelper myDB;
    Button create, query, quit;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

      Select = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SelectStatement);
      create = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Create);
      query = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Query);
      quit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Quit);

     //   Select.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

        tableS tables1 = new tableS("S01", "Smith", "London");
        tableS tables2 = new tableS("S02", "Jones", "Paris");
        tableS tables3 = new tableS("S03", "Blake", "Paris");
        tableS tables4 = new tableS("S04", "Clark", "London");
        /*tableS tables5 = new tableS("S05", "Adams", "Athens");
        tableS tables6 = new tableS("S06", "Gracia", "Austin");
        tableS tables7 = new tableS("S07", "Thomas", "El Paso");
        tableS tables8 = new tableS("S08", "Jonas", "New York");
        tableS tables9 = new tableS("S09", "Zeeman", "Dallas"); */

        /*tableP tablep1 = new tableP("P01","Nut", "0.13", "London");
        tableP tablep2 = new tableP("P02","Bolt", "0.25", "Paris");
        tableP tablep3 = new tableP("P03","Screw", "0.09", "Rome");
        tableP tablep4 = new tableP("P04","Screw", "0.10", "London");
        tableP tablep5 = new tableP("P05","Cam", "5.26", "Paris");
        tableP tablep6 = new tableP("P06","Cog", "3.75", "London");
        tableP tablep7 = new tableP("P07","Washer", "0.11", "El Paso");
        tableP tablep8 = new tableP("P08","Nut", "0.13", "Austin");
        tableP tablep9 = new tableP("P09","Nail", "0.01", "Rome");
        tableP tablep10 = new tableP("P010","Gear", "9.99", "Houston");
        tableP tablep11 = new tableP("P011","Tack", "0.01", "Dallas");
        tableP tablep12 = new tableP("P012","Wheel", "2.30", "Paris");

        tableSP tablesp1 = new tableSP("S01", "P01","300");
        tableSP tablesp2 = new tableSP("S01", "P02","200");
        tableSP tablesp3 = new tableSP("S01", "P03","400");
        tableSP tablesp4 = new tableSP("S01", "P04","200");
        tableSP tablesp5 = new tableSP("S01", "P05","100");
        tableSP tablesp6 = new tableSP("S01", "P06","100");
        tableSP tablesp7 = new tableSP("S01", "P12","50");
        tableSP tablesp8 = new tableSP("S02", "P01","300");
        tableSP tablesp9 = new tableSP("S02", "P02","400");
        tableSP tablesp10 = new tableSP("S03", "P02","200");
        tableSP tablesp11 = new tableSP("S04", "P02","200");
        tableSP tablesp12 = new tableSP("S04", "P04","300");
        tableSP tablesp13 = new tableSP("S04", "P05","400");
        tableSP tablesp14 = new tableSP("S05", "P01","50");
        tableSP tablesp15 = new tableSP("S05", "P09","150");
        tableSP tablesp16 = new tableSP("S05", "P011","320");
        tableSP tablesp17 = new tableSP("S06", "P02","150");
        tableSP tablesp18 = new tableSP("S06", "P12","825");
        tableSP tablesp19 = new tableSP("S08", "P08","180");
        tableSP tablesp20 = new tableSP("S08", "P11","250");
        tableSP tablesp21 = new tableSP("S09", "P01","100");
        tableSP tablesp22 = new tableSP("S09", "P03","200");
        tableSP tablesp23 = new tableSP("S09", "P04","100");
        tableSP tablesp24 = new tableSP("S09", "P07","300");
        tableSP tablesp25 = new tableSP("S09", "P10","100");
        tableSP tablesp26 = new tableSP("S09", "P12","200");*/

        // add them
        myDB.insertdata(tables1);
        myDB.insertdata(tables2);
        myDB.insertdata(tables3);
        myDB.insertdata(tables4);
       /* myDB.insertdata(tables5);
        myDB.insertdata(tables6);
        myDB.insertdata(tables7);
        myDB.insertdata(tables8);
        myDB.insertdata(tables9); */
       /* myDB.insertdatap(tablep1);
        myDB.insertdatap(tablep2);
        myDB.insertdatap(tablep3);
        myDB.insertdatap(tablep4);
        myDB.insertdatap(tablep5);
        myDB.insertdatap(tablep6);
        myDB.insertdatap(tablep7);
        myDB.insertdatap(tablep8);
        myDB.insertdatap(tablep9);
        myDB.insertdatap(tablep10);
        myDB.insertdatap(tablep11);
        myDB.insertdatap(tablep12);


        myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp1);
        myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp2);
        myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp3);
        myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp4);
        myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp5);
        myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp6);
        myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp7);
        myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp8);
        myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp9);
        myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp10);
        myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp11);
        myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp12);
        myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp13);
        myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp14);
        myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp15);
        myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp16);
        myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp17);
        myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp18);
        myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp19);
        myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp20);
        myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp21);
        myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp22);
        myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp23);
        myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp24);
        myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp25);
        myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp26); */


        create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }



    public boolean onCreateOptionMenu (Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
        return true;
    }


    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        int id = item.getItemId();
        return true;
    }
}
```

tables.java

```
package com.rough.problem.problem9;


public class tableS {

    private String sno;
    private String sname;
    private String city;


    public tableS() {
    }

    public tableS(String sno , String sname, String city) {
        this.sno = sno;
        this.sname = sname;
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getSno() {
        return sno;
    }

    public void setSno(String sno) {
        this.sno = sno;
    }

    public String getSname() {
        return sname;
    }

    public void setSname(String sname) {
        this.sname = sname;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return sno + "  " + sname + "  " + city ;
    }

}
```

Comment: What I think is because you insert is in `onCreate()` method and this method can be called when you have a rotation screen so you try to insert data more than one time. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Answer (score 0):

**I suspect that you are seeing the error in the log but that it is not actually resulting in an exception/crash.**

That is that even though you are effectively using `INSERT OR IGNORE` (i.e. using the `insert` convenience method) that the unique constraint failed message(s) will still appear in the log.

e.g. using a copy of your code results in  :-

```
07-27 21:07:03.237 1233-1233/com.rough.problem.project9 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 14396: Landroid/widget/Button;.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults (I)V
07-27 21:07:03.237 1233-1233/com.rough.problem.project9 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0004
07-27 21:07:03.245 1233-1233/com.rough.problem.project9 E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting sno=S01 sname=Smith city=London
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column sno is not unique (code 19)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:775)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
        at com.rough.problem.project9.DatabaseHelper.insertdata(DatabaseHelper.java:98)
        at com.rough.problem.project9.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:82)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Error inserting sno=S02 sname=Jones city=Paris
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column sno is not unique (code 19)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:775)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
        at com.rough.problem.project9.DatabaseHelper.insertdata(DatabaseHelper.java:98)
        at com.rough.problem.project9.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:83)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-27 21:07:03.249 1233-1233/com.rough.problem.project9 E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting sno=S03 sname=Blake city=Paris
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column sno is not unique (code 19)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:775)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
        at com.rough.problem.project9.DatabaseHelper.insertdata(DatabaseHelper.java:98)
        at com.rough.problem.project9.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:84)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Error inserting sno=S04 sname=Clark city=London
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column sno is not unique (code 19)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:775)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
        at com.rough.problem.project9.DatabaseHelper.insertdata(DatabaseHelper.java:98)
        at com.rough.problem.project9.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:85)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-27 21:07:03.281 1233-1233/com.rough.problem.project9 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.getLayoutDirection, referenced from method android.support.v4.view.MarginLayoutParamsCompat.getLayoutDirection
07-27 21:07:03.281 1233-1233/com.rough.problem.project9 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 13844: Landroid/view/ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams;.getLayoutDirection ()I
```

As you can see there are 4 exceptions one per insert because the rows already exist, thus showing that processing continues. If you were to delete the App's data and rerun you would not get any exceptions, but then next run would result in exceptions.

Now if you were to change `db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);` to `db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, values);` then you would get :-

```
07-27 21:22:24.393 1397-1397/com.rough.problem.project9 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-27 21:22:24.393 1397-1397/com.rough.problem.project9 W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6231288)
07-27 21:22:24.393 1397-1397/com.rough.problem.project9 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rough.problem.project9/com.rough.problem.project9.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column sno is not unique (code 19)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column sno is not unique (code 19)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:775)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(SQLiteDatabase.java:1365)
        at com.rough.problem.project9.DatabaseHelper.insertdata(DatabaseHelper.java:98)
        at com.rough.problem.project9.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:82)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The difference now being is that you get a **`FATAL RUNTIME EXCEPTION`** and processing is stopped and you'd get the **Unfortunately, Project9 has stopped** crash.

**Note this is not recommending using the `insertOrThrow` method, this has just been used to demonstrate the difference between a trapped but printed exception and an exception that is not trapped andthus results in a crash.**

You solution could be to either check to see if the database has been populated or to look at providing the database as a a pre-existing database as an asset.

The former could be relatively simple to introduce by :-

1. Changing the definition of the constant **`TABLE_NAME`** from **`private`** to **`public`**.
2. In the MainActivity class adding a method addData(), moving all the code that adds(inserts) the data into the method.
3. Adding code to check to see if the table is already populated, and if so returning before adding any data.

   1. You can utilise the DatabaseUtils `queryNumEntries` to do this.

e.g. the **`addData`** method could be :-

```
private void addData() {

    //<<<<<<<<<< NOTE TABLE_NAME in the DatabaseHelper class change from private to public

    if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(myDB.getWritableDatabase(),DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME) > 0) return;

    tableS tables1 = new tableS("S01", "Smith", "London");
    tableS tables2 = new tableS("S02", "Jones", "Paris");
    tableS tables3 = new tableS("S03", "Blake", "Paris");
    tableS tables4 = new tableS("S04", "Clark", "London");
    /*tableS tables5 = new tableS("S05", "Adams", "Athens");
    tableS tables6 = new tableS("S06", "Gracia", "Austin");
    tableS tables7 = new tableS("S07", "Thomas", "El Paso");
    tableS tables8 = new tableS("S08", "Jonas", "New York");
    tableS tables9 = new tableS("S09", "Zeeman", "Dallas"); */

    /*tableP tablep1 = new tableP("P01","Nut", "0.13", "London");
    tableP tablep2 = new tableP("P02","Bolt", "0.25", "Paris");
    tableP tablep3 = new tableP("P03","Screw", "0.09", "Rome");
    tableP tablep4 = new tableP("P04","Screw", "0.10", "London");
    tableP tablep5 = new tableP("P05","Cam", "5.26", "Paris");
    tableP tablep6 = new tableP("P06","Cog", "3.75", "London");
    tableP tablep7 = new tableP("P07","Washer", "0.11", "El Paso");
    tableP tablep8 = new tableP("P08","Nut", "0.13", "Austin");
    tableP tablep9 = new tableP("P09","Nail", "0.01", "Rome");
    tableP tablep10 = new tableP("P010","Gear", "9.99", "Houston");
    tableP tablep11 = new tableP("P011","Tack", "0.01", "Dallas");
    tableP tablep12 = new tableP("P012","Wheel", "2.30", "Paris");

    tableSP tablesp1 = new tableSP("S01", "P01","300");
    tableSP tablesp2 = new tableSP("S01", "P02","200");
    tableSP tablesp3 = new tableSP("S01", "P03","400");
    tableSP tablesp4 = new tableSP("S01", "P04","200");
    tableSP tablesp5 = new tableSP("S01", "P05","100");
    tableSP tablesp6 = new tableSP("S01", "P06","100");
    tableSP tablesp7 = new tableSP("S01", "P12","50");
    tableSP tablesp8 = new tableSP("S02", "P01","300");
    tableSP tablesp9 = new tableSP("S02", "P02","400");
    tableSP tablesp10 = new tableSP("S03", "P02","200");
    tableSP tablesp11 = new tableSP("S04", "P02","200");
    tableSP tablesp12 = new tableSP("S04", "P04","300");
    tableSP tablesp13 = new tableSP("S04", "P05","400");
    tableSP tablesp14 = new tableSP("S05", "P01","50");
    tableSP tablesp15 = new tableSP("S05", "P09","150");
    tableSP tablesp16 = new tableSP("S05", "P011","320");
    tableSP tablesp17 = new tableSP("S06", "P02","150");
    tableSP tablesp18 = new tableSP("S06", "P12","825");
    tableSP tablesp19 = new tableSP("S08", "P08","180");
    tableSP tablesp20 = new tableSP("S08", "P11","250");
    tableSP tablesp21 = new tableSP("S09", "P01","100");
    tableSP tablesp22 = new tableSP("S09", "P03","200");
    tableSP tablesp23 = new tableSP("S09", "P04","100");
    tableSP tablesp24 = new tableSP("S09", "P07","300");
    tableSP tablesp25 = new tableSP("S09", "P10","100");
    tableSP tablesp26 = new tableSP("S09", "P12","200");*/

    // add them
    myDB.insertdata(tables1);
    myDB.insertdata(tables2);
    myDB.insertdata(tables3);
    myDB.insertdata(tables4);
   /* myDB.insertdata(tables5);
    myDB.insertdata(tables6);
    myDB.insertdata(tables7);
    myDB.insertdata(tables8);
    myDB.insertdata(tables9); */
   /* myDB.insertdatap(tablep1);
    myDB.insertdatap(tablep2);
    myDB.insertdatap(tablep3);
    myDB.insertdatap(tablep4);
    myDB.insertdatap(tablep5);
    myDB.insertdatap(tablep6);
    myDB.insertdatap(tablep7);
    myDB.insertdatap(tablep8);
    myDB.insertdatap(tablep9);
    myDB.insertdatap(tablep10);
    myDB.insertdatap(tablep11);
    myDB.insertdatap(tablep12);


    myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp1);
    myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp2);
    myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp3);
    myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp4);
    myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp5);
    myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp6);
    myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp7);
    myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp8);
    myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp9);
    myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp10);
    myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp11);
    myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp12);
    myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp13);
    myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp14);
    myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp15);
    myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp16);
    myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp17);
    myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp18);
    myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp19);
    myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp20);
    myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp21);
    myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp22);
    myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp23);
    myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp24);
    myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp25);
    myDB.insertdatasp(tablesp26); */

}
```

Comment: I figured it out. I was getting this error because I did not delete my .db file from device file explorer before creating new tables under same .db file name.

Comment: @DhvaniPatel As explained deleting the file (as deleting the App would do) would temporarily circumvent the issue as there would be no conflicts. However, again as explained, there really was no actual issue, rather you just misread the log.